# Deploy new container revision to Cloud Run without changing Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I am setting up a CI&CD environment for a GCP project involves Cloud Run. While setting up everything via Terraform is pretty much straightforward, I cannot figure out how to update the environment when the code changes.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#terraform_1) says:

> 1. Make a change to the configuration file.

But that couples the application deployment to terraform configuration, which should be responsible only for infrastructure deployment.

Ideally, I use terraform to provision the infrastructure, and another CI step to build and deploy the container.

Is there a best-practice here?

Relevant sources: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/koef10/how_to_manage_containers_and_cloud_run_in_a_gcp/).

Comment: In this situation your Terraform would only perform an Update operation to modify the environment variables. If you do mean "container", then there does not need to be another build and deploy. If you meant "image" instead, then an update to its environment would require a new build. You may need to go serverless to do this most efficiently though.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you, but I am not sure I fully understand. I am "serverless", and my goal is to update the actual image when the code change (like merge to `master` branch).

Comment: You could rebuild and push the new layer of the image with its new tag without Terraform in that case.

Comment: I can use `gcloud build submit` but what won't create a new Cloud Run revision. I can also use `gcloud run deploy` but I'll have to use a different tag than the current tag, won't I?

Comment: Also, I must set an image path via Terraform. If I'll redeploy outside of terraform, next time `terraform apply` will run it'll override the previous deployment.

Comment: You have to change the variable, not the terraform, but you have to provide the latest full image name (with the SHA). Else, Terraform will compate latest with latest, no change, no new revision.

Comment: But that will mean Terraform will be responsible for application deployment, which is not desirable.

Comment: @galah92 facing the same issue, have you found any viable solution to this?

Comment: I ended up separating Cloud Run service creation (in Terraform) and deployment to two different workflows. The key component was to make terraform ignore the actual deployed image, which I achieved using `ignore_changes = [template[0].spec[0].containers[0].image]`

Comment: @galah92 I suggest you add this comment as an answer to your question and accept it yourself. This helps others :)

Comment: @galah92 I split up my workflows with GA too and I added that code in the lifecycle block for "google_cloud_run_service" resource. But get this error 
Error: Error updating Service "locations/<region>/namespaces/<project_id>/services/<service_name>": googleapi: Error 409: Revision named 'service-name-00002-lap' with different configuration already exists. Could you share your code inside the resource please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up separating Cloud Run service creation (which is still done in Terraform) and deployment to two different workflows.

The key component was to make terraform ignore the actual deployed image so that when the code deployment workflow is done, terraform won't complained that the Cloud Run image is different from the one it manages. I achieved this by setting `ignore_changes = [template[0].spec[0].containers[0].image]` on the `google_cloud_run_service` resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can also point your cloud run service or job at a specific image's tag. In this case, you can point at an image's `latest` tag. Then manage the `latest` tag on your images as part of your application deployment when it's added a newer image to your container repository.

A couple of things you'll need to take note of is that GCP artifact repository immuatable tags will no longer work and if you want to explicitly get cloud run to load the new image, you'll have to create a new revision. Alternatively, you can wait for cloud run to naturally create a new container with your new `latest` image. One way to explicitly force a new revision and container is to set the template.revision field in your terraform to a random id. Then run terraform apply with the replace flag on the random variable used in the template.revision. This will explicitly deploy a new revision of the cloud run service without any infrastructure changes using the image with the `latest` tag applied.