How to upload public docker image to Artifact Registry in GCP
There is the code to create to create a Cloud Run with an image from an Artifact Registry repository from the Terraform documentation.

resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my_repo" {
  location      = "us-west1"
  repository_id = "my-repository"
  format        = "DOCKER"
}

data "google_artifact_registry_docker_image" "my_image" {
  repository = google_artifact_registry_repository.my_repo.id
  image      = "my-image"
  tag        = "my-tag"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
 # ...

  template {
    containers {
      image = data.google_artifact_registry_docker_image.my_image.self_link
    }
  }
}

Here is the code to create a Cloud Run from a public image in GCP using Terraform from the Terraform documentation.
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-service"
  location = "us-central1"
  ingress = "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_ALL"

  template {
    containers {
      image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
    }
  }
}

But how to I upload a (dummy) public image to my Artifact registry to make my Cloud Run use it ?
More context:
I'd like to create an Artifact registry repository with a dummy public images that all my Cloud Run will use at creation with terraform. Then, in a CI/CD pipeline, I will upload them but I can't find a simple way to do it (upload a dummy public image to my artifact registry) using Terraform for now.

I don't undestand why you want to put a dummy image in your artifact registry. Set a variable in the image name, point to the public Cloud Run hello image for the deployment, and for the subsequent pipeline, put in your var your target image. What's your challenge in that pattern?

First of all, salut, ravi d'avoir un commentaire du "grand" guillaume! The challenge with your solution, if I understood it correctly is that I will have to do a double terraform apply before&after var changes. I wanted something that I could to create and destroy quickly. The idea behind dummy containers (not images ;)) in AR is that they are put in place as placeholder so that I can just update them (Cloud Run will use the latest). Basically avoid a multiple steps configuration of architecture, you run it once, you go to the code. I'm quite new to this, is this approach sound ?

Ok, you want to "hardcode" your container name in your terraform and simply push the code, the new container, and terraform always deploy the same latest image, correct?

Not really "hardcode". I want a dummy image to be uploaded in Artifact Registry with a custom name (that name can be a variable, the real name of my container). Terraform will deploy my Cloud Run with the dummy container (from Artifact Registry), I will push another versions later and Cloud Run will use the latest all the time. I run Terraform once and only focus on pushing new versions of my container.

How do you plan to deploy the subsequent images? with gcloud command and not with terraform?

Yes! That's the idea.

Hmmm, maybe a bad idea. What happens if you have to add variables/secret to Cloud Run (or change them)? What happens if you have to change Cloud Run config (CPU, memory, concurrency,...)? It could work of course, but personally I don't like asymetric pipeline (when I change the code I'm doing that, when I change the config I'm doing something different. And when I change both in the same time,what happens? Race conditions?)

Ok, to avoid extended discussion, I think my real problem is that I don't see how this can be done symetrically. In Cloud Function, there's an archive ressource to zip my code then send it to my Cloud Function but how to make Terraform build my image, store it in my Artifact Registry to keep things in sync I don't know. I searched but just found an unanswered question (in my sense), can you please help he/her and me by answering it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71915003/deploy-new-container-revision-to-cloud-run-without-changing-terraform

Yes, understood. What I am doing: I use cloud build with 2 steps: 1st create the container (and push it), 2nd deploy with Terraform. The trick here is to use a container name (or at least its tag) at each build. Use the commit sha or the timestamp as an image tag. Like that, I have a container name that is pushed to artifact registry and passed in parameter to my terraform. Consistency OK, problem solved.

sorry to come to your discussion with a few questions 1) your step 1 - did you mean create an image (rather than a container?) and push it to the AR? 2) I know in terraform at least 2 ways how the image can be build on a CICD 'runner' machine and that image is pushed to the AR (and subsequently used in the same terrafrom 'apply' to deploy a cloud run from that AR image) - do we need the 2 separate steps at all?

Here is the work around I found, it is dirty but it seems to work. I used a null ressource to run a script to pull then push an image to my newly created repository.
resource "null_resource" "dummy_image" {

      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<EOF
            gcloud auth print-access-token \
            --impersonate-service-account <sa-name>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com | docker login \
            -u oauth2accesstoken \
            --password-stdin https://${var.location}-docker.pkg.dev
            docker pull us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello 
            docker tag us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello  ${var.location}-docker.pkg.dev/${var.project_id}/${google_artifact_registry_repository.my_repo.name}/demo
            docker push ${var.location}-docker.pkg.dev/${var.project_id}/${google_artifact_registry_repository.my_repo.name}/demo
        EOF
      }
}

data "google_artifact_registry_docker_image" "my_image" {
  repository_id = google_artifact_registry_repository.my_repo.repository_id
  image_name = "demo"
  depends_on = [ null_resource.dummy_image ]
}

resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
  # ...
    template {
    containers {
      image = data.google_artifact_registry_docker_image.my_image.self_link 
    }
  depends_on = [ null_resource.dummy_image ]
}

You can find more references about how to login using docker to Artifact Registry here.
Note: The name of the docker image (demo) can be a variable.
